# Music BroadcastReceiver not working properly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm making an app in which I need to create a BroadcastReceiver because there are certain things I need to do when music is playing.

Here's what I have:

(BroadcastReceiver Class)

```
public class MusicBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context , Intent arg1 )
    {       
        AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        manager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        System.out.println("Playing: " + manager.isMusicActive());
        if (manager.isMusicActive())
        {
            //context.startService(new Intent(context, TimerService.class));
            AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimerService.class);
            PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            long timeToWake = System.currentTimeMillis() + ( 30 * 1000);
            mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToWake, pendIntent);
            System.out.println("Started service");
        }
    }
}
```

When music starts playing, the receiver gets called, perfect behavior. But when I call "manager.isMusicActive()", this doesn't return the correct value. In my main activity I created a button which when pressed would check if music is active, using the same code. And there "isMusicActive()" works perfectly (Here's the code for that)

```
btn_CheckMusic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                if (mAudioManager.isMusicActive())
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SERVICECMD);
                    i.putExtra(CMDNAME, CMDSTOP);
                    getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Music Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Music isn't playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

so I have no idea what is causing it to mess up in the Receiver class